# Apache Velocity in Android("unable to find resource")

Tags: java, android, velocity

I use this code to reach temp.vm, but I get this error. what should I change in code, file location or Mainfest

P.S.  It is new project, so I have standard Manifest
I have tried to save file in Resources, Assets and in main path

**2021-05-20 17:11:27.617 17303-17303/com.example.printer E/org.apache.velocity: ResourceManager : unable to find resource '123/temp.vm' in any resource loader.**

```
    VelocityEngine velocityEngine = new VelocityEngine();
    velocityEngine.init();
    velocityEngine.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER, "classpath");
    velocityEngine.setProperty("classpath.resource.loader.class", ClasspathResourceLoader.class.getName());
    Template t = velocityEngine.getTemplate("123/temp.vm");
    VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
    context.put("name", "World");
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    t.merge( context, writer );
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure putting the template files in the java source tree is enough for them to be visible from the classpath. We would need to see your gradle script. Typically, resources meant to be in the classpath (by typically including them in the final jar) are located in a `resources` directory. In development mode, you can try to manually add the `java` directory to the classpath.